# Facebook bot : should all the experience be in Facebook Messenger or not?

Tags: interaction-design, interface, info-visualisation

Me and my friend are working on a Facebook bot. We have a question where we have opposite viewpoints, so we made the choice to ask this community.

To me, if you provide a Facebook-bot user experience your user expects to stay within the Facebook ecosystem and all the information should be presented in the messenger interface.

For him it doesnt matter if at the second or third step you extract the user from Facebook's ecosystem to our website/application.

Which option would provide the best user experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It essentially depends on the type of Application you're developing.

If it's a bot that gets things done and replies from time to time according to your query, I think the **Messenger app is the better platform to choose**.

I think the days of people using bots on a Website are over since people are mostly mobile these days.

Instead of having one to open the browser, type an Url and then go to your website to have a rather non-native experience, it's much better to do lesser work by implementing your work on a platform optimized both for Web and Mobile and will be native to the conversation.

As far as  UX is concerned - I think native applications will work far better by offering platform recognition, lesser cost, updates provided by Facebook itself.

You would not only be doing efficient cost cutting but also be aiming to provide superior User Experience.